# Move Specific Rows depending on Filtering Keywords within unknown amount of rows using Google Sheets Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I do SEO, and therefore I have a lot of keywords flowing around in different spreadsheets. I'd like a way to filter these into seperate sheets based on specific filters, but I can't for the life of me, figure out how to do this in Google Apps Script.

Criteria I set myself for this to work out:

- A list of strings and their corresponding volumes are entered in column 1+2.
- A list of filter-words are written in column 3.
- The script has to create a new sheet for each of the filter words and move the strings + volumes into these different sheets if the string contains a filter word.

Example:
Filter words: `Apple, Banana, Pineapple`

String: "The Apple Was Big", Volume: "100"

The script would move the string and volume into the sheet called "Apple" on row 1

(Beware, I'm in no means experienced in coding)
I believe you can use the following structure:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= column3RowAmount; i++){ //Run as long as there are more filter words
   create(column3Row[i]); //create a new sheet with the name of the filter word
   for(let j = 0; j <= column1RowAmount; j++){ //Run as long as there are more keywords
      if(column1Row[j].indexOf(column3Row[i]) >= 0){ //If the Row in column 1 contains the filter word
         column1Row[j].moveToSheet(column3Row[i]); // Make sure not to move Column 3, but only 1+2
      }
   }
}
```

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YIMyGmmfZdy094gwuJNxFmTd8h7NOLnA8KevZrGtdU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Your goal is to create a sheet for every filter-word in column **C**. Then copy the data in columns **A, B** but only the rows that **include** the filter-word to the corresponding sheet.
- For starters, you need to get the filter-word list. You can get the full range of column **C** and filter out the empty cells:

  ```
  const sh_names = sh.getRange('C1:C').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!='');
  ```
- Similarly, you need to get the data in columns **A** and **B**:

  ```
  const data = sh.getRange('A1:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  ```
- The next step is to iterate over `sh_names` and for every element / filter-word, check if a sheet with that name exists. If it does not exist, then create a sheet with that name, if it exists then skip the creation part:

  ```
    if(!ss.getSheetByName(s)){
    ss.insertSheet().setName(s);}
  ```
- The next step is to filter `data` on the rows that [include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the filter-word:

  ```
  let f_data = data.filter(r=>r[0].includes(s));
  ```
- Finally, check if the length of the data is bigger than `0`, otherwise there is not data to use and set the values of `data` to the corresponding sheet:

  `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,f_data.length,f_data[0].length).setValues(f_data)`

### Solution

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Ark1');
  const filter_sh = ss.getSheetByName('Filter');
  const data = sh.getRange('A1:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const sh_names = filter_sh.getRange('A1:A'+filter_sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  sh_names.forEach(s=>{
    if(!ss.getSheetByName(s)){
    ss.insertSheet().setName(s);}
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s);   
    let f_data = data.filter(r=>r[0].includes(s));
    if(f_data.length>0){
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,f_data.length,f_data[0].length).setValues(f_data);}
}); 
}
```

Comment: Well, worked first time around, now it just said: "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 4, file "Code").

Is there a way to delete the rows that has been moved in the original sheet?

Comment: @JonasSkalbo it says that because you **changed** the name of the sheet from `Ark1` to `Keywords`. Find `Ark1` in the code I provided and replace it with `Keywords`. Also, stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. If you have a follow up question please post a **new** question. Thanks and sorry for the incovenience

Comment: I have created a new questions, thanks for the directions, and thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This function will place all of your results into column 4 next to the appropriate word rather than creating a page for each word.  So it runs much faster.

```
function stringswords() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sr=2;
  const rgd=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,2);
  const data=rgd.getDisplayValues();
  const rgw=sh.getRange(sr,3,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1);
  const words=rgw.getDisplayValues().flat();
  const wiObj={};
  words.forEach(function(w,i){wiObj[w]=i});
  const rgr=sh.getRange(sr,4,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1);
  rgr.clearContent();
  var results=rgr.getValues();
  words.forEach(function(w,i,A){
    data.forEach(function(r,j,D) {
      if(data[j][0] && data[j][0].indexOf(w)!=-1) {
        results[wiObj[w]][0]+=Utilities.formatString('String:%s Vol:%s\n',data[j][0],data[j][1]);
      }
    });
  });
  rgr.setValues(results);
}
```

Image of Data and output:

[image]